# Comparar posiciones de un array $miarray[n]

Tags: php, array

¿Cómo podría validar los valores de un mismo array, es decir, por ejemplo:

```
if ($miarray[0] < $miarray[1])
{
    //$miarray[0] toma el valor de $miarray[1]
}
if ($miarray[2] > $miarray[3])
{
    //$miarray[3] toma el valor de $miarray[2]
} 

//... etcétera...
```

Pero la cosa es que tengo `$miarray[n]`, y no sé cómo hacerlo con `n` posiciones.

Lo estaba haciendo con `for`, nada más que lo hice con 2 `for` para ver cómo me resultaba.

```
for ($a=0; $a < count($miarray) ; $a++) 
{ 
    for ($b=0; $b < count($miarray); $b++) { 
        if($miarray[$a] > $miarray[$b])
        {
            $miarray[$b] = $miarray[$a];

        }
        else
        {
            $miarray[$a] = $miarray[$b];
        }
    }
}
```

En cierta parte con estos 2 `for` me escoge el más alto y lo cambia, pero pone el valor mayor en todos los `$miarray[]`, y lo que necesito es que solo ponga el valor mayor entre `$miarray[0]` y `$miarray[1]`, después que verifique el mayor entre `$miarray[2]` y `$miarray[3]`, y así sucesivamente...

Answer (score 1):

Este código resuelve tu problema:

```
for( $i = 0; $i <  count($miarray) - 1; $i++){

    if( $miarray[$i] < $miarray[$i + 1] ){
        $miarray[$i] = $miarray[$i + 1] ;
    }
    else{
        $miarray[$i + 1] = $miarray[$i] ;
    }

    i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya existen funciones en php donde te permite ordenar un array, el método se llamar `sort($myarray)`

También permite configurar el sort, aquí te dejo la información oficial de php

http://php.net/manual/es/function.sort.php

Si bien lo quieres hacer de forma manual, en internet puedes buscar "metodo burbuja", "quicksort",etc. Que son métodos de ordenamiento, si los buscas en internet para php estoy seguro que ya habrá alguno hecho y bien explicado